# Associate EditText with a TextView for labeling purposes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Hi I am learning Android programming and have run into an issue that I couldn't get a clear answer to through researching.

I have a TextView which serves as a label for my EditText.  I have a method which checks if the EditText is an empty String.  If the string is empty I want to be able to get a reference to the TextView that corresponds to that EditText in order to make a toast saying something like "please enter a value for ".

I've looked into getLabelFor/setLabelFor but is there a way to do this in the layout XML?

What is best practice for this type of functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're describing a functionally that is build in to `EditText`.  There is a special field you can define in xml called [hint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ahint), which is the recommended way to label an `EditText` rather than a nearby `TextView`.  Additionally, `EditText` has a method called `setError()` ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)).  If the user attempts to hit a submit button, for example, you can check to see if the `EditText` is empty and if so, call `setError()`.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the following is the thing that you need

```
TextWatcher inputTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if (s.toString().equals("")) {
            textView.setText("please enter a value for ..");
        } else {
            textView.setText("<the textedit is not empty>");
        }
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 

    }
};

editText.addTextChangedListener(inputTextWatcher);
```